# Rectifying data source for MXD file using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, georeferencing

I tried to rectify my data source on ArcMap but was unable to locate my data file which is an MXD file.

How can I rectify the data source for an MXD file ?

Comment: What Version of ArcMap are you using? What do you mean "Rectify data source" are you missing data in your mxd? When you open the mxd does the layer have a red ! ? If so you can reset the source by clicking that red exclamation point and navigate to where the file is located. Or you can right-click the mxd in ArcCatalogue and repair the data sources for all layers in the right-click menu.

Comment: An MXD is not a data file, it's a *metadata* file. It does not store data sources, just the locations to those sources.

Comment: Oh, thank you. It worked